# Application run failed spring boot aplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot development. I created my first Spring Boot application and when i tried to run it as spring boot app i got this message.
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my configuration classe :

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class AppConfiguration {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hellow() {
        return "hellow world";
    }

}
```

my pom.xml look like:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>Hello World Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is already included by `spring-boot-starter-web`. Remove it and retry. Also, do you have configuration classes?

Comment: it does not worked when i removed  spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Comment: yes i have configuration classe```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class AppConfiguration {
@RequestMapping("/hello")
 public String hellow() {
  return "hellow world";
 }
}```

Comment: Please post the entire log.

Comment: How do you start this application?

Comment: i don't understand your question how do you start this application ? do you mean how i run it if so i use run as spring boot app

Comment: just for your attention this is my first web app using spring

Comment: I mean do you run it with `mvn spring-boot:run` or from an IDE?

Comment: i use eclipse donat ide

Comment: Try run it from the command line with: `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: it says that maven 
is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an executable program or a batch file. 
I think the problem is at this level

Comment: So you did not even install maven. Maybe you should start learning the basics first, then move to creating web applications.

Comment: yes i think i still lack notions to start an app

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web application you are creating?

If not, try setting this property in your application.yml file:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

If so, you need to have a [ServletWebServerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/server/ServletWebServerFactory.html) bean. One example:

```
MyConfiguration {
  @Bean 
  ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory(){
  return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
  }
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html).

Oh, and install maven.